# Camunda web app refusing connection on localhost

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, camunda, connection-refused

suddenly my Camunda web app is refusing connection. When I do `localhost:8080`, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` by `localhost`

`http://localhost:8081/` is working (where my Spring Boot application is offering REST API).

```
 ____                                 _         ____  ____  __  __
/ ___| __ _ _ __ ___  _   _ _ __   __| | __ _  | __ )|  _ \|  \/  |
| |   / _` | '_ ` _ \| | | | '_ \ / _` |/ _` | |  _ \| |_) | |\/| |
| |__| (_| | | | | | | |_| | | | | (_| | (_| | | |_) |  __/| |  | |
\____/\__,_|_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|\__,_|\__,_| |____/|_|   |_|  |_|

  Spring-Boot:  (v2.0.2.RELEASE)
  Camunda BPM: (v7.9.0-ee)
  Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v3.0.0)

2019-11-14 11:24:22.351  INFO 988 --- [           main] d.c.c.CarorderprocessApplication         : Starting CarorderprocessApplication on U2007750s-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 988 (/Users/u2007750/CC/Develop/projects/Kfz-Bestellprozess/backend/carorderprocess/target/classes started by u2007750 in /Users/u2007750/CC/Develop/projects/Kfz-Bestellprozess/backend/carorderprocess)
2019-11-14 11:24:22.354  INFO 988 --- [           main] d.c.c.CarorderprocessApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-14 11:24:22.393  INFO 988 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@73a1e9a9: startup date [Thu Nov 14 11:24:22 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-11-14 11:24:23.040  INFO 988 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-11-14 11:24:23.323  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2019-11-14 11:24:23.348  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-11-14 11:24:23.348  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2019-11-14 11:24:23.351  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/u2007750/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-11-14 11:24:23.415  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-11-14 11:24:23.415  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1024 ms
2019-11-14 11:24:23.546  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-11-14 11:24:23.553  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-14 11:24:23.553  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-14 11:24:23.553  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-14 11:24:23.554  INFO 988 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-11-14 11:24:23.624  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2019-11-14 11:24:23.696  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB040 Setting up jobExecutor with corePoolSize=3, maxPoolSize:10
2019-11-14 11:24:23.703  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService  'camundaTaskExecutor'
2019-11-14 11:24:23.819  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.cfg               : ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'CompositeProcessEnginePlugin[genericPropertiesConfiguration, camundaProcessEngineConfiguration, camundaDatasourceConfiguration, camundaJobConfiguration, camundaHistoryConfiguration, camundaMetricsConfiguration, camundaAuthorizationConfiguration, CreateAdminUserConfiguration[adminUser=AdminUserProperty[id=kermit, firstName=Kermit, lastName=Kermit, email=kermit@localhost, password=superSecret]], enterLicenseKeyConfiguration, failedJobConfiguration, CreateFilterConfiguration[filterName=All tasks], disableDeploymentResourcePattern]' activated on process engine 'default'
2019-11-14 11:24:23.821  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB020 ProcessApplication enabled: autoDeployment via springConfiguration#deploymentResourcePattern is disabled
2019-11-14 11:24:26.399  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.engine.sql'
2019-11-14 11:24:26.406  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.history.sql'
2019-11-14 11:24:26.412  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'identity' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.identity.sql'
2019-11-14 11:24:26.418  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'case.engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.case.engine.sql'
2019-11-14 11:24:26.420  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'case.history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.case.history.sql'
2019-11-14 11:24:26.423  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'decision.engine' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.decision.engine.sql'
2019-11-14 11:24:26.426  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03016 Performing database operation 'create' on component 'decision.history' with resource 'org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create/activiti.h2.create.decision.history.sql'
2019-11-14 11:24:26.439  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03067 No history level property found in database
2019-11-14 11:24:26.439  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.persistence       : ENGINE-03065 Creating historyLevel property in database for level: HistoryLevelFull(name=full, id=3)
2019-11-14 11:24:26.453  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine                   : ENGINE-00001 Process Engine default created.
2019-11-14 11:24:26.516  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB010 creating initital Admin User: AdminUserProperty[id=kermit, firstName=Kermit, lastName=Kermit, email=kermit@localhost, password=superSecret]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.524  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB015 create initial filter: id=ef3d28a5-06c8-11ea-8d8e-9e512cc933d1 name=All tasks
2019-11-14 11:24:26.658  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.742  INFO 988 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@73a1e9a9: startup date [Thu Nov 14 11:24:22 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-11-14 11:24:26.779  INFO 988 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String de.countandcare.carorderprocess.controller.OrderController.index()
2019-11-14 11:24:26.783  INFO 988 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-11-14 11:24:26.783  INFO 988 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-11-14 11:24:26.793  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.802  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.802  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.802  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/lib/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.802  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/api/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.802  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/app/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.834  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [META-INF/resources/index.html]
2019-11-14 11:24:26.925  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.c.b.s.b.s.w.f.LazyInitRegistration     : lazy initialized org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazySecurityFilter@428ad7b1
2019-11-14 11:24:26.925  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.c.b.s.b.s.w.f.LazyInitRegistration     : lazy initialized org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyProcessEnginesFilter@452e7202
2019-11-14 11:24:27.036  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-11-14 11:24:27.058  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.container                : ENGINE-08024 Found processes.xml file at file:/Users/u2007750/CC/Develop/projects/Kfz-Bestellprozess/backend/carorderprocess/target/classes/META-INF/processes.xml
2019-11-14 11:24:27.059  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.container                : ENGINE-08025 Detected empty processes.xml file, using default values
2019-11-14 11:24:27.062  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.container                : ENGINE-08023 Deployment summary for process archive 'carorderprocessApplication': 

        orderProcess-PoolVehicles-2019-10-08.bpmn

2019-11-14 11:24:27.203  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.application              : ENGINE-07021 ProcessApplication 'carorderprocessApplication' registered for DB deployments [ef918a36-06c8-11ea-8d8e-9e512cc933d1]. Will execute process definitions 

        OrderProcess[version: 1, id: OrderProcess:1:efa427d8-06c8-11ea-8d8e-9e512cc933d1]
Deployment does not provide any case definitions.
2019-11-14 11:24:27.212  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.container                : ENGINE-08050 Process application carorderprocessApplication successfully deployed
2019-11-14 11:24:27.239  INFO 988 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-14 11:24:27.243  INFO 988 --- [           main] d.c.c.CarorderprocessApplication         : Started CarorderprocessApplication in 5.223 seconds (JVM running for 5.883)
2019-11-14 11:24:27.245  INFO 988 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14014 Starting up the JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.components.jobexecutor.SpringJobExecutor].
2019-11-14 11:24:27.246  INFO 988 --- [ingJobExecutor]] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE-14018 JobExecutor[org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.components.jobexecutor.SpringJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
2019-11-14 11:24:32.847  INFO 988 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-11-14 11:24:32.847  INFO 988 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2019-11-14 11:24:32.861  INFO 988 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 14 ms
```

Comment: Connection refused error means that no service is listening to the port (in case of localhost). So I guess your instance fails to start on port 8080. Can you observe `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080` message when running camunda on 8080 port?

Comment: In my `application.properties`, I have set `server.port=8081`. With that I want that my Spring Boot Rest API listens on `8081` and that my camunda dashboard appears on `8080`

Comment: When I remove the entry from `application.properties`. The Spring Boot Rest API listens on 8080 and the controller method i called succesfully and returns the value. But still no camunda dashboard....

Comment: From what I've understood: You are running Camunda dashboard using Spring Boot Starter. The Spring Boot project with Camunda starter is the same one that also serves your Rest API. If those are correct, then embedded tomcat which is initialized is the `same`, and that means that your Camunda dashboard and Rest API will always listen to the same port (I omit possibilites to create a kindof nginx reverse proxy, etc.). Please let me know if I've misunderstood something

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. But how can I achieve that? I want to call `localhost:8081/functionxyz` and that `GET` function should then call `runtimeService` and do something with the process

Comment: If you really need this feature (which I doubt), put a router in front of your app and let that rewrite connections to :8081 to the webapp and :8080 to rest ...

Comment: @farahm did you find a solution for this issue cause I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @Maria-Elena actually I was able to solve this. let me know if you are still interested

Comment: @farahm thanks a lot I solved it it was an authentication problem

Answer (score 1):

By setting *server.port=8081* in *application.properties*, you are configuring the whole http server to listen on port 8081. So the web application will not be available on 8080.

From the description I cannot tell how your "Spring Boot Rest API" is configured, but I assume it interferes with the camunda web application because it uses the same base path.

If your objective is to expose your *Spring Data* based API under a different URL, then setting a different base path will likely solve the issue. Set

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/uniquetext
```

(and possibly spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType = application/json)

and access your API under this base path instead.

If this does not solve the issue, including a *logback.xml* in *src/main/resources* and adjusting the log levels to your needs may help you diagnose the issue. Example:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.apache.ibatis" level="info" />
    <logger name="javax.activation" level="info" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="info" />
    <logger name="org.camunda" level="info" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: So the REST API will then be available on http://localhost:8081/uniquetext/functionxyz ? – farahm 8 mins ago

Comment: Say you are using spring data for your API and included a PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, Long> implementation in the classpath and set the basepath property as described, then your service should be available at  http://127.0.0.1:8080/service/accounts while the camunda web app should remain accessible

Comment: Would it be bad from an architectural point of view, if both camunda and spring boot would listen to the same port? lets say `http://localhost:8080/app/welcome/default/#!/welcome` would show the camunda dashboard and `http://localhost/functionxyz` would be a normal REST call to the contoller (which has GET method `functionxyz` )?

Comment: If the web application and custom API are deployed on the same server, then this will be the case. If you are targeting a micro services architecture then you would want to isolate the service so you can start/stop/upgrade/scale it independent from the web application. In this scenario you can just use two spring boot projects and start the service on a port which differs from the engine server. This comes with increased operations effort though. The best target architecture depends on the use case.